# > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:kotlinCompilerClasspath'

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, visual-studio-code

My flutter project is not installing in real device kindly help me to resolve this error
here is the error:

```
   > Could not load module metadata from C:\Users\usama\.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.96\descriptors\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-common\1.3.50\edb68b65d2dd9b547bbf59d703899938\descriptor.bin

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I have tried many codes but no any response.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clean your `cache` folder.

Just follow this steps:

- Step 1: Open the terminal
- Step 2: `cd C:\Users\usama\.gradle`
- Step 3: `rm -r caches\`
- Step 4: Now clean or rebuild the project